# Spring 3.2.1 - trailing slash is not getting mapped; removing the slash from client request is mapped correctly

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.2.1, and have come across an odd issue related to mapping a request to an appropriate @Controller method.  For example, this URL is being used by our clients (but it doesn't work):

http://server:port/appcontext**/clinics/1271/patients/?status=ALL&tz_offset=240**

headers are: {Accept=application/json, Content-Type=text/html;charset=utf-8}

I've tried all of the recommended actions, i.e. using RequestMappingHandlerMapping, including the trailing slash in my list of "value" paths on the @RequestMapping annotation.

Here's the Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class ClinicController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/clinic/{givenClinicId}/patients", "/clinic/{givenClinicId}/patients/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody Object retrievePatients(
        @PathVariable String givenClinicId,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value="status") String status,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) String date,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "tz_offset") String givenTzOffset,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "filter") String givenPatientFilter)
    {
        // do some work here
    }
}
```

Here's the spring configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"       class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
             <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
             <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
             <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="true"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here's the relevant web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is the log output demonstrating the RequestMappingHandlerMapping appropriately picking up the configuration from the @Controller:

```
2015-03-11 18:41:04 INFO  ethod.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  -
Mapped "{[/clinic/{givenClinicId}/patients || /clinic/{givenClinicId}/patients/],
methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],
custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object com.fmcna.csg.pci.controller.ClinicController
.retrievePatients(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

And yet, the following URL fails with an HTTP 404:

```
protocol://localhost:8080/patientcheckin/clinic/1271/patients/?status=ALL
```

but this works fine:

```
protocol://localhost:8080/patientcheckin/clinic/1271/patients?status=ALL
```

I feel this is something really simple but I'm at my wit's end.  Oh yeah, one other thing: the code works fine in PROD today, but not in DEV.  We do have different containers (Weblogic in PROD, Tomcat in DEV) but this hasn't presented itself as an issue in the past.

One other caveat, we have numerous external business partners that use this service and it is not feasible to change the API to support a trailing slash.  Also, I really don't want to hack this with a redirect, but would rather prefer a solid answer on why Spring is failing to resolve the mapping.

Help please!!

OK, this can be closed as answered. There are some oddities with respect to the various versions of Tomcat.  Tomcat 6 everything worked as expected.  However, I recently converted to a Macbook Pro and installed Tomcat 7, where everything did NOT work as it had on Tomcat 6.  It was rather a simple solution to address the problem, as illustrated below, by simply modifying the url-mapping for my servlet to "/*" instead of "/".  The application now deploys with no issues on both Tomcat 6, Tomcat 7 and Weblogic, so I'm quite happy with the suggestion.

There is an article out there on the internet that was very illustrative of the problem, and I believe it should be read and understood by more people since there are quite a few questions out there related to this particular issue of URI/URL construction.  Here's a link to that document:

https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/

Comment: are you trying to make it to use the /?status instead of just ?status.  the later is the more common.  I just tested something with a trailing backslash but I had to add it to my security config to make it work, but this format is not common

Comment: try changing your <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> to     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> and see if solves the issue

Comment: useTrailingSlashMatch by default value is true. You don't have to set it explicity. Couple of questions, i see your dispacter servlet startup is set to 2. Is there any other servlet?

Comment: Sorry guys, for some reason I didn't get email about your responses.  I've not added the "/*" to the configuration, but it wasn't required before.  If you look below, you'll see that I've identified the culprit to be Tomcat.  This was a good resource for reviewing the old school reasons for the status and how our standards have deviated from the expectation, which have now become the de facto standards.  Cheers, and thank you for your help! [link](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/)

Comment: minion - you've some very good observational skills!  The other servlet defined is actually commented out for deployment to Tomcat.  It is a servlet that will return static file resources in Weblogic.   <servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.FileServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
But, as I said, this is commented out for local deployment.  But a great question nonetheless!

Comment: faljbour - our clients leverage various javascript libraries, and is often the case, when executing Ajax calls, the local environment, i.e. browser, will automatically append a "/" to the URL, which results in the odd separation between resource and query parameters.  The impact is that the service needs to respond to a wide assortment of constructed URIs that effectively represent the same end point.

Comment: faljbour - I did what you'd asked and added the "/*" to the servlet-mapping and it worked brilliantly in both servers! After doing this, I went and chatted with my devs and asked them how they were testing locally.  To my dismay they've been deploying to SIT; violating one of our key conventions to test locally.  However, your insight will allow my guys to at least get back to adhering to the convention.  Thanks for the simple suggestion which is worth a considerable, "Thank you!!"